# Flutter create PopupMenuButton with a Text and an Icon instead of single Icon

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a PopUpMenuButton to let the user choose the language of the app and I want to display a Text of the currently selected language as the Button to open the menu.
So something like this:
[image]
I currently just have an Icon as the button to open the Menu with a tooltip:
[image]

```
BlocBuilder<LanguageBloc, LanguageState>(builder: (context, state) {
  return PopupMenuButton(
    offset: const Offset(0, 40),
    elevation: 2,
    iconSize: 18,
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.g_translate,
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
      PopupMenuItem(
          value: "en",
          child: Row(children: [
            Text("English",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2),
            const SizedBox(width: 15),
            Icon(
              Icons.check_circle,
              size: 18,
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.60),
            )
          ])),
      PopupMenuItem(
          value: "de",
          child: Text("Deutsch",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2)),
    ],
  );
})
```

I could just put a Text infront of the Icon but clicking on the Text wouldn't open the `Popupenu` so I would need an implementation that allows to open the menu when clicking on the Text or the Icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TextButton.icon` as a child:

```
 PopupMenuButton(
    offset: const Offset(0, 40),
    elevation: 2,
    child: TextButton.icon(
                label: Text(
                 'Your label'
                  ),
                ),
                icon: Icon(
                 Icons.g_translate,
                 color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                   ),
                onPressed: () {
                //do logic, or keep it empty
                },
              ),
```

Comment: I don't think that works, if `onPressed` is empty, the pop up menu won't appear when you click the button.

Comment: `onPressed: null` and the popup opens.

Comment: `onPressed: null` should deactivate the button's clickability.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a "beautiful" button integrating the PopupMenu inside a TextButon.icon

```
    Tooltip(
        message: "Change main color",
        child: TextButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.color_lens),
            label: const Text("Color"),
            onPressed: () {
              showMenu(
                  context: context,
                  position: const RelativeRect.fromLTRB(100, 100, 100, 100),
                  items: List.generate(colorOptions.length, (index) {
                    return PopupMenuItem(
                        value: index,
                        onTap: () => handleTap(index),
                        child: Wrap(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.color_lens_outlined,
                                color: colorOptions[index],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20), child: Text(colorText[index]))
                          ],
                        ));
                  }));
            }),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html):

> One of child or icon may be provided, but not both. If icon is provided, then PopupMenuButton behaves like an IconButton.

```
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: //...,
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert), // -> Specify the Icon
              itemBuilder: (context) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: "ItemOne",
                  child: Text('Item 1'),
                ),
                const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: "ItemTwo",
                  child: Text('Item 2'),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ]),
      body: //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you would do it in Flutter 3+:

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(itemBuilder: (context) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
  PopupMenuItem(child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        language = "English";
      });
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
    child: const Text("English"),
  )),
  PopupMenuItem(child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        language = "Deutsch";
      });
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
    child: const Text("Deutsch"),
  ))
],
child: Text(language)),
```